# Linux server icmp security

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, icmp

I have a Linux router, it is connecting to internet via pppoe with dynamic IP

and I would like it NOT to respond to ping (or any other kind of icmp) from outside (internet), BUT I would like that ping (and all icmp, like traceroute, tcptraceroute, mtr, etc.) from inside (LAN) and from server to outside targets to work, how can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I'm guessing that by "Linux router" you mean a computer running Linux acting as a router.*

**Drop icmp traffic from the outside:**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP
```

- **-A INPUT**: packets destined to local sockets.
- **-p icmp**: specifies protocol to use, icmp in this case
- **--icmp-type echo-request**: specifies the type of icmp packets being filtered
- **-j DROP**: what to do when matching the filter. `DROP` will just drop them without sending any error message to the host pinging.

You could also use `REJECT` instead of `DROP`, which would send an error message.

**Allow icmp traffic to the outside:**

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply -j ACCEPT
```

- **-A OUTPUT**: packets generated locally.
- **-p icmp**: specifies protocol to use, icmp in this case
- **--icmp-type echo-reply**: specifies the type of icmp packets being filtered
- **-j ACCEPT**: what to do when matching the filter. We are accepting **replies only**

Comment: I had my doubts about your answer be cause you use general all firewall rules, but I tested it and it is working, so, first of all *THANK YOU* and second, I would appreciate if you explain more ... *PLEASE* :)

Comment: I edited the answer with some info. You have all the info [here](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables.man.html) anyways.

Comment: For completeness sake and performance, I would suggest actually dropping that in the raw table so that the state table is not hit.  `iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've got the icmp extension to iptables available and drop packets with an icmp type of 8 on the external facing interface (--protocol icmp --icmp-type 8)

Comment: seems they are in my Linux distro by default, I didn't search for then but both your switches works well (protocol icmp and icmp echo) !